# How to find the numerical of Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, lately, I've been wanting to find the Numerical IP (like 12.345.67.89) rather than the redirect IP (mc.example.net). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The domain name that you can enter as a minecraft server is the same as any other web address, so any service that lets you find the IP of a website will also work on these minecraft servers.

For instance, these sites:

- https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html
- http://www.getip.com/
- http://ipinfo.info/html/ip_checker.php

Comment: This is the exact same thing as ModDL's post. Except I'm using a remote machine to ping it.

Comment: @JosephChristianHefley It is, however I posted mine first and it was operating system neutral, so I don't see any reason to remove it. Either using a service, or pinging the server yourself. This is how you get the IP.... A domain name is just a textural representation of an IP address. If you're looking for something else, you will need to make your question clearer. It seems like you're confused about what a domain name is.

Answer (score -1):

Open command prompt and type `ping <Redirect IP>`. Wait a few seconds and it will say `reply from <Numerical IP>`.

Comment: This will not work. It will instead ping a web resource, not the server.